# How to override menuitem click event in QtDesigner?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer

I'm trying to make a C++ Qt Widget Application using QtDesigner,
 I have to override some menu items clicked events,
 so how to override the `QAction` clicked event from .ui?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you are looking for this:

[image: Action go to triggered slot]

Comment: If you don't see that list, Click Rightmouseclick outside window you are creating and select "action Editor". Got this?

Comment: Very Good! Thanks a lot, Really you helped me.